# Dynamic Columns With Calculated Values

Tags: dynamic, pivot

1) **StructureTable:**

```
StrId   StrName Figure    Base      On                                  
1       Basic   40        Percent   Total                                   
2       D.A.    3495      Amount    Total                                   
3       O.A.    0         Remaining Total
```

2) **SalaryTable**

```
StaffId StaffName   Salary                                          
1       Ram         25000                                           
2       Shyam       40000                                           
3       Hari        30000                                           
4       Ganesh      15000
```

3) **IncrementTable**

```
StaffId IncAmt                                              
1       5000                                                
2       3000                                                
3       2000                                                
4       4000
```

Desired Columns Resulted Output by Pivot or others:

```
StaffId StaffName   Basic_Salary   D.A_Salary   O.A_Salary   Total_Salary   Basic_Inc   D.A_Inc O.A_Inc Total_Inc    Basic_Total    D.A_Total   O.A_Total   Total_Total
1       Ram         10000           3495        18495         25000         2000        0       3000     5000        12000           3495       21495        30000
2       Shyam       16000           3495        27495         40000         1200        0       1800     3000        17200           3495       29295        43000
3       Hari        12000           3495        21495         30000          800        0       1200     2000        12800           3495       22695        32000
4       Ganesh      6000            3495        12495         15000         1600        0       2400     4000         7600           3495       14895        19000
        Total       44000          13980        79980        110000         5600        0       8400    14000        49600          13980       88380       124000
```

Comment: I fundamentally improved the formatting of the tables. They should be readable by now!

Comment: very good formatting you done... also request you to do formatting my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748290/fifo-stock-valuation-through-cte-recursion post

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself? I showed you how to do it.